# Multivariate timeseries classification for each group in a dataset

Tags: time-series, lstm, rnn, multiclass-classification, forecasting

Let's say, I have the following dataset:

```
station |    date   | min_temp | feature2 | feature3 | snow |
  1     |  01-11-11 |    1     |   5      |    22    | true |
  1     |  02-11-11 |    1     |   5      |    22    | true |
  2     |  01-11-11 |    1     |   5      |    22    | true |
  2     |  02-11-11 |    1     |   5      |    22    | true |
```

I want to forecast if it will snow on the following date for each station in the dataset, I am not sure what is the best approach for this.

1. Split the dataset into multiple datasets with respect to station.

   This does not seem like a good solution to me because I will
   basically train the model for `n` datasets. (for each station)
2. Include stations as one-hot encoded dummy variables to use them as features for the classifier

   I am not sure about this one. I will increase the number of columns(features) and thus the dimension. Also, how do I make the prediction at the end? Just predict the features for the day?
3. Just train as it as, hoping the model learns the difference between stations.

   Again, how do I make the prediction at the end?

I am not sure, what is the best way to perform this task. Are there other better methods?

Answer (score 0):

use a random forest classifier and then optimize parameters by using random search cross validation.  Validation will tell how the model will perform with unknown data.  https://towardsdatascience.com/hyperparameter-tuning-the-random-forest-in-python-using-scikit-learn-28d2aa77dd74